# JQuery parentsUntil() in combination with height() not working properly

Tags: jquery, html

I have this HTML (the comments show how JQuery should go up to the last parent element I need)

```
<div id="profilesHolder">
<div class="parentArrow"></div>

<!-- THE LAST PARENT JQUERY SHOULD FIND -->
<div class="scrapItemParent">
    <img class="scrapProfilePic" src=" static/img/user/personalProfilePicture/mod_50_50/0d6e6c14fb915c8db38ee4d17e0d4631cb4538a9.jpg" />

    <!-- THE SECOND PARENT JQUERY SHOULD FIND -->
    <div class="scrapContent">Test Scrap no. 1. <a class="scrapLink" href="http://google.com">google.com</a> <a class="scrapLink" href="http://bing.com">bing.com</a> <a class="scrapLink" href="http://nokia.com">nokia.com</a><br />
        <div class="scrapImg">
            <img class="scrapImgItem" src="../../../scrapll_m/static/img/user/scrap/orig/12f3c8ce2aa2626fbaaf6bec54933a6185f9e63d.jpg" alt="Scrap Image" />
            <img class="scrapImgItem" src="../../../scrapll_m/static/img/user/scrap/orig/1df38f26091c23f942bc1529a0391b8309892c23.jpg" alt="Scrap Image" />
            <img class="scrapImgItem" src="../../../scrapll_m/static/img/user/scrap/orig/ef101b36d5ed6a420fcef6ddc7a13aa18da4c121.jpg" alt="Scrap Image" />
            <img class="scrapImgItem" src="../../../scrapll_m/static/img/user/scrap/orig/601eb46725685f9390efae57af1c39596accc705.jpg" alt="Scrap Image" />
        </div>
        <iframe class="scrapVideo" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Ys6-DCotJt8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe><br />

        <!-- THE FIRST PARENT JQUERY SHOULD FIND -->
        <span class="scrapTime">2014-05-21 17:03:21<br />Erol Simsir
            <a class="replyLink" href="#">Reply</a> <!-- STARTING POINT TO FIND THE PARENT DIV -->
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the JS:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.replyLink').click(function(){ 
        var currentHeight = $(this).parentsUntil("#profilesHolder").height();
        alert(currentHeight);
    });
});
```

Using $(window).load() was a tip given to someone with the same issue, but it didn't change anything for me ($(document).ready() neither).

Anyway, the JS shows that JQuery should look for the parent element of the element '.replyLink' all the way up to the element '#profilesHolder'. That means that the element '.scrapItemParent' should be found by JQuery. This goes well, because when I do this JS for example:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.replyLink').click(function(){
        $(this).parentsUntil("#profilesHolder").css("background", "red");
    });
});
```

This code works and it changes the background of the right parent element, but when I want to get the height of the parent element JQuery has found, it keeps showing me 30, which is the height of the direct parent element of '.replyLink'. So when I use the height() function right after the parentsUntil() function the parentsUntil() function stops after finding the height of the direct parent instead of going all the way up the the '.scrapItemParent' element.

Who can help me out with this?

Comment: What you exactly want to achieve with `parentsUntil()`? You need all of the parent element heights? or just the `#profilesHolder`?

Comment: Just the height of the .scrapItemParent.

Comment: Why not simply do this `$(this).closest('.scrapItemParent').height()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try switching from parentsUntil() to closest(). I tested that in this [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8N9Xh/) and it seems to work.

```
$(this).closest("#profilesHolder").height();
```

Fiddle Example - http://jsfiddle.net/8N9Xh/

Answer (score 0):

Since ids are unique, you can just use

```
$("#profilesHolder").height();
```